A movie about a fluffy cloud being supressed by industry
In the 90s, I saw a trailer for a live-action children's movie about a fluffy cloud falling from the sky and being found by a child.
The cloud explains to the child that the industry is producing so much exhaust that it confuses the cloud, which actually would like to go back to its family.
The cloud looked like a sheep. I think the sheep was talking in human language, since, if I remember correctly, the sheep itself was explaining the above-mentioned story to the child in that trailer (the child was a girl, if I remember correctly). The child was roughly in the age range of 6–9 years. I can't remember any adults in the trailer, as it was the cloud telling its story to the girl.
The trailer was in German. But I don't know if it was a German production. It was a rather low-budget movie.
Can anyone identify this movie?

https://youtu.be/c2RhYxuYFD4?si=uDrFHZcdmMV3s8ph Professor Balthazar?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By0Mx-SrqFo&ab_channel=MagneticMemoryMuseum - I was thinking it might be a TV special like this one.

@user182601 Yeah, I am very sure about it.

Is it perhaps Zirri - Das Wolkenschaf (1993)?

The German film is about the 11-year old girl Christine, or 'Schiene', who lives in the Baumstrasse (Tree Street), where not a single tree grows. The local liquor factory pumps black sheep into the sky.
When Christine and her parents visit her grandfather, who is a shepherd, they see a white cloud sheep falling from the sky. The sheep can talk, introduces itself as Zirri, and explains it was pushed from the sky by the black sheep, and needs to get back up there. Schiene and Zirri try different ways to get her back in the sky, and ultimately it is the local fire brigade that is able to build a ladder tall enough to bring Zirri back home.
The movie seems quite low-budget. Here is the IMDb page. The story is based on a book by Fred Rodrian.

The following video is AFAICT not a trailer, as the title implies, but a scene from the film. It seems to be the only video on YouTube about the film, though:



There seems to be an animated version of the story, as well, from 1960.

The Trailer I had seen was on a TV ad (or for previewing it as it was broadcast at somepoint on taht TV channel). The youtube video you posted is not the trailer I had seen, so ultimately I can't tell untill I have seen the movie (just ordered it on amazon). But especially the description sounds pretty much like what I had seen back then.

Thanks for your help, that is infact the movie I was looking for :)
